# Vectorising array operations

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In Excel, if we want to apply f(x)=x^2-1 to each element of a range (say `A1:A10`) we can write the array formula `{=A1:A10^2-1}`.

If I read the same range into a VBA function (which ends up being a 2D `Variant`), how do I do the same thing without looping?

In general, what are some (if any) FP tools available in VBA for dealing with arrays?

Comment: I think vb 6 does not have any help to do mathematical operations with arrays. I made a library time ago but when I was learning to code. Maybe you can find usefull mathematical functions if you google them. And yes those function will surely loop A LOT! as @makah says you can use excel functions too.

Comment: FYI - A range array will always be a 2D array in Excel.  This is a common point of confusion.  See this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) for more details.

Comment: @PortlandRunner that is a good point, and also the array base will always be 1...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this `Range("B1").FormulaArray = A1:A10^2-1`.